# Override @PropertySource with @TestPropertySource in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have my Spring Boot main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("file:/my/file/properties")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
  //main method
}
```

I'm reading properties from an external file (using `@PropertySource`). Now, I have an integration test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes= Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
@TestPropertySource("file:/my/test/file/properties") // <---
public class MyTest {
  //some tests
}
```

I need to use another external properties file, different from the indicated in `@PropertySource` in `Application` class. For that reason, I have added `@TestPropertySource`, but seems that this annotation is not overriding the `@PropertySource`.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
```

and place test properties file into `src/test/resources`

Comment: I tested, my case it works with:
@TestPropertySource(locations = "file:./src/test/resources/application.properties")

Answer (score 0):

In Java8 you can "repeat" an Annotation like:

```
@PropertySource(value = "file:./src/main/resources/mydefault.properties")
@PropertySource(value = "file:./src/test/resources/override.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

This way, the latter overwrites properties from the first file if available.

Comment: Did not work for me, the second file does not override properties of the first...

Comment: Repeating an annotation does not `overwrite` or override - it `adds`.

Comment: Actually worked for me.
I have a module client which is used by other modules then in my module custom-client-test I added override.properties file which really overrides props from mydefault.properties in client module (of course override.properties doesn't exist in client  module)